# DbContext GetValidationErrors and unit test code coverage

Tags: unit-testing, entity-framework-4.3

I'm not trying to unit test EF, but my business logic.

```
        if (_context.GetValidationErrors.Count > 0)
        {

            foreach (DbEntityValidationResult validationResult in _context.ValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (DbValidationError error in validationResult.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    // add ErrorMessage to a list

                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

I'm using Mock in my unit tests. I can easily mock the count of the validation errors, but mocking the lists in the foreach loops has me stumped. I'd like to be able to mock the loops for the sake of code coverage.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but I've yet to find a solution. You cannot throw DbEntityValidationResult without a valid context.